# Clean shutdown of express.js + mongodb server (using node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, shutdown

I have node.js webserver using express.js and mongodb as a datastore. This server is being controlled by `runit`, and I am trying to implement a way to gracefully shut down the server.

I am implementing signal handlers for `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM`, and I am aware that you can stop listening for new connections by calling `.close()` on the object returned by `createServer()`. So far so good.

However, even when no more requests are forthcoming, there may be a number of requests already in the system that needs to finish before I can close the database.

I am using a mongodb ReplicaSet, and I figure that if I just call `db.close()` right away, that some of these requests may fail in some manner. Is there some way to close the database in a way that allows pending database queries to finish or do I have to manually have a +/- counter to see how many "active" queries are pending, and then wait to shutdown until it reaches 0?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to manually ensure that you are in a clean state to shut down as the driver does not wait flush out the remaining operations before shutting down.

Feel free to log a ticket for the feature on

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/